# Calculate loss from intermediate layer

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Say I have an intermediate embedding layer (say at first layer) in a neural network of four layers. A desired property of the embedding matrix is that the sparser the better. Say the output from neural network is o1, is it ok to make the score like
score(o1)+sparse(embedding matrix)? That is we not only use the final output, also the intermediate embedding layer (intermediate output)?